# MSVCP100D.dll was not found,

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, windows-xp

Application has failed to start because MSVCR100.dll was not found, reinstalling application ? But my questions is when MSVCR100.dll file store in window xp or any sftware install time store or XP install time ? pleas help me friend ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSVCR100.dll was not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600359/msvcr100-dll-was-not-found)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

MSVCP100D.dll is part of visual studio 10. Last char D stans for debug. Is not granted that this dll is installed in all systems. You have to distribute it with your application.

@down voter: it's obvious that you have to distribute the no-debug version...

Comment: License restrictions do not allow redistribution of the Debug runtime DLLs.